# display week of day for date stored in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, server

I want to display for each day in the last 7 days mount of purchases in the following format:

```
{
    "sunday":30,
    "monday":20,
    ...
}
```

one purchase on the database looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 603fcbcc691d8a5ecc320059
    productId: "603fc917a569f565687e2626"
    clientId: "1"
    totalPrice: 50
    date: 2021-03-02T00:00:00.000+00:00        // a date object
}

Purchase.aggregate([
                    { "$match": { "date": {$gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } } },
                    { "$group": { 
                        "_id": { "day": { $substrCP: [ "$date", 0, 10 ] } },
                        "count": { $sum: 1 }
                    }},
                    { "$sort" : { "_id.day": 1}},
                    
                ])
```

i run this code and i got:

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": "2021-02-28"
        },
        "count": 30
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": "2021-03-01"
        },
        "count": 20
    }
]
```

Comment: Whenever one has to work with date/time values I recommend the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. It makes your life much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, but I could not find any readymade method in mongodb which gives me Sunday for value 1. thats why keeping switch statement.

```
collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "date": { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { $dayOfWeek: "$date" },
            "count": { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: {
                $push: {
                    k: {
                        $switch: {
                            branches: [
                                {
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 1] },
                                    then: "monday"
                                },
                                {
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 2] },
                                    then: "tuesday"
                                },
                                {
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 3] },
                                    then: "wednesday"
                                },
                                
{
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 4] },
                                    then: "thursday"
                                },
                               
 {
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 5] },
                                    then: "friday"
                                },
                                
{
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 6] },
                                    then: "saturday"
                                },

                                {
                                    case: { $eq: ["$_id", 7] },
                                    then: "sunday"
                                }]
                        }
                    },
                    v: "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using switch statement i used this:
before agregate() i initialized an array with values:

```
const days = ['','Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
```

and did the agregate like that:

```
Purchase.aggregate([
                { "$match": { "date": { $gte: new Date((new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) } } },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$date",
                        "count": { $sum: 1 }
                    }
                },
                { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } },
                { 
                    "$project": { 
                        "_id": 0, 
                        "count": 1, 
                        "day": { $arrayElemAt: [ days, { $dayOfWeek: "$_id" } ] }
                    } 
                },
                { 
                    "$group": { 
                        "_id": null, 
                        "data": { $push: { k: "$day", v: "$count" } }
                    } 
                },
                {
                    "$project": { 
                        "data": { $arrayToObject: "$data" }, 
                        "_id": 0 
                    } 
                }
            ])
```

i run this and i got the wanted answer:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "Sun": 30,
            "Mon": 20
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: this looks good, just one thing 1-> Mon and 2-> Tues .... 7-> Sunday when using $dayOfWeek.

that array should be
['',Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']; ?